# send Notification to device using by tag value using pushwoosh

Tags: php, pushwoosh

So i am developing an application which requires push notifications and i'm using pushwoosh. but currently i'm stuck on how to send targeted notifications to a device by a tag value. 
I am using [http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh/]
Any help will be appreciated. thanks

```
$filter = '';
$request = CreateTargetedMessageRequest::create()
->setContent($options['body'])
->setData(
    [
        'custom' => 'json data'
    ]
)
->setDevicesFilter($filter);
$pushwoosh->createTargetedMessage($request);
```

what i want is the value for the filter

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it myself. I used the `setCondition()` method to specify the tag name and value for what i wanted.

```
$request = CreateMessageRequest::create()
    ->addNotification(Notification::create()

        ->setContent($options['body'])
        ->setConditions([
            IntCondition::create('userId')->eq($user_id)
        ]));


// Call the REST Web Service
$response = $pushwoosh->createMessage($request);
```